# Google still indexing old URLs

Tags: seo

I am using Joomla 3.0 for my site
Last month, I have submitted my site to google using Google Web Master Tools

Last week I installed category listing plugin called 'DM Pinboard'.
Because of this plugin, all the articles which under the categories, changed its URL.

So in google, already indexed old articles. When user click a link in SERP displaying the following error.
500 - View not found [name, type, prefix]: pb, html, pbView!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ETS2.jpg)

I think I have to inform Google, that I have changed my URLs. 
I don't know how to inform it.
Please help me to solve this problem

Comment: If you have a reasonable number of urls you can use com_redirect (in the components menu but you need to enable the plugin) to permanently redirect the urls.  Google understand permanent redirection and will update.

Comment: If any of the answers below have solved your issue, then consider to accept it as the right one.

Answer (score 4):

You need to create a new sitemap using a component like [xmap](http://www.jooxmap.com/) and submit it to [Google Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/)

301 Htaccess redirection will also help you redirect old urls to new using the correct pattern
[301 Redirects](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/htaccess/301-redirects/)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a number of urls that can be manageable, then your best option should be to create 301 redirects for all the old urls to the new ones, using the Redirect Component, or any other 3rd party SEF extension you want.

This way, Google will learn about your new urls and will replace them in its index from time to time, but also any possible visitor that will come from a SERP page with an old url, will not get the error page, but he will be redirected to the actual content.

Also, sitemap submissions and Google Webmaster Tools is your friend here. Create an account in Google for Webmasters Tools, from where you would be able to get reports about all such possible errors, you could also submit your new urls or sitemap and also manipulate at some level how Google will interact with your pages and also provides a Remove URLs feature, which you might want to use, to remove some of those dead urls.